# Laravel Session methods just working once

Tags: php, laravel, session, laravel-5, laravel-5.5

I'm using Laravel 5.5 and trying to store a variable into the session. I'm using the global helper `session()`.

So I do this:

```
session(['a' => 'b']);

dd(session()->all())
```

just for testing, and there it is, however, when I refresh, and I remove the first line, the `a` variable is gone?

Also, `forget()`, `flush()`, and all other methods just work once in the request. Once you refresh, it's all gone.

Comment: Do this little experiment. Visit this page where you set the session and check your laravel session cookies When you visit the page next time check if the cookie value is the same as the previous time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dd Helper function in Laravel will dump the variable and end the execution of the script. So, you are ending this execution

```
session(['a' => 'b']);
```

This script does not execute at all.

Try returning the script or try using PHP native functions like var_dump() or print_r()

Comment: I thought the session function would be the same that doing `$_SESSION['a'] = 'b';`. So it needs a response to the request to store/remove data?

Comment: You can either use the global session helper or via the request function. You are using the global session helper, and is perfectly valid, it's same as doing $_SESSION['a']='b'

Answer (score 0):

As far as I remember you shouldn't use `dd()` for such tests. Just use `var_dump` and everything should work as expected.

Also if it still doesn't work make sure you are testing it inside `web` middleware group